# What characters must be escaped in HTML5 attributes?

Tags: html

**Preface**

Similar questions exist, but they are not specific enough for my needs. The answer to this question seems to differ for HTML4, XHTML, and HTML5, with no clear answers for the latter. This question is specific to *attribute strings* in HTML5 and should not address any other versions of HTML or escaping that is not specific to strings used as attribute values.

**Question**

I am writing code that uses custom data attributes, and I want to make sure the strings I put into these attributes are properly escaped. I want to do the minimum amount of escaping necessary for the values to be correct and safe. I am using double-quotes (`"`) as the attribute delimiters. Currently, the only escaping I'm doing is replacing double-quotes with `&quot;`. Are there any other characters that need to be escaped?

Comment: I don't think the answer has changed from HTML 4 to HTML5 (and, in the case of quoted attribute values, any flavor of XML since XML doesn't allow unquoted attribute values). Have you discovered otherwise?

Comment: @BoltClock — `class="&foo"` is valid HTML 5 but invalid HTML 4

Comment: @Quentin: Where foo is not a valid character reference right? If so, interesting.

Comment: @BoltClock — Yup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters that need escaping are:

- Whatever character you use to delimit the attribute value (either `"` or `'`)
- Ampersands unless the characters that follow them do not form a character reference
- Characters which can't be represented by the current character encoding

> I want to do the minimum amount of escaping necessary for the values to be correct and safe.

I recommend aiming to be *simple* over *minimum*. You are less likely to make a mistake that way.

- Always (except inside `<script>` and `<style>` elements which are special cased) escape the five characters which can have special meaning in HTML: `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, and `'`.
- Use UTF-8 everywhere

These guidelines work inside attribute values, inside text nodes, for HTML 4, for HTML 5 and for XML (including XHTML).